# Merge password tags

Tags: discussion, retag-request

These are the password tags:

- [passwords](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/passwords) x 730
- [password-management](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/password-management) x 127
- [password-recovery](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/password-recovery) x 90
- [password-protection](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/password-protection) x 52
- [password-generation](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/password-generation) x 11
- [password-prompts](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/password-prompts) x 4

Do we really need all of them? I feel like they're too specific and I don't think we need so many tags for password related questions. I think we can merge / remove some of them. What do you think?

Comment: If anything's wrong, I'd say that `[passwords]` is too unspecific. Password management, recovery and protection definitely deserve their own tags, IMO.

Comment: If any of them should be merged, then that would be [password-management], [password-protection], and [password-generation]. [password-recovery] should be a separate tag.

Answer (score 2):

On [security.se], there's [passwords](https://security.stackexchange.com/tags/passwords/info), [password-management](https://security.stackexchange.com/tags/password-management/info) and [password-policy](https://security.stackexchange.com/tags/password-policy/info). Password policy is more of an administrator subject.

Password generation goes hand in hand with password choices which are usually asked with [passwords](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/passwords), so I suggest merging that one.

[password-protection](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/password-protection) is a bit of a mess, as it covers password storage (preventing others from obtaining your password), setting something to be password-protected ([confidentiality](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/confidentiality)?), and coping with a feature that includes a password protection (→ [authentication](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/authentication)). It needs manual cleanup.

[password-recovery](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/password-recovery) is a separate concept worth keeping.

Answer (score 1):

I removed [password-prompts](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/password-prompts) for the time being. I agree with @slhck, [passwords](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/passwords) could be improved.